# How i can create Reg Expression for the following number?

Tags: c#, regex

In c#, i gotta verify user inputs. Can someone tell me what will be the reg ex in order to verify this expression 12345-4521.

```
<12345> = Any five digits only
<-> = only hyphen
<4521> = Any four digits only but last digit should either be 0 or 1.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
^\d{5}-\d{3}[01]$
```

Comment: `[01]` is more concise than `(0|1)`.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
\d{5}-\d{3}[01]
```

### Explanation:

- The `\d` matches any digit from 0 through 9
- The `[01]` matches a 0 or 1
- The `{5}` and `{3}` tells it to match exactly that number of the previous expression

This is pretty basic stuff.  When you get a chance, you should read [a good tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), which covers this (and much more).

Comment: Your solution is missing caret. donc not working as per need. Accepting more than 5 chars

Comment: No, it's not anchored; if you're not testing the length of the string you need to add `^` and `$`.  Many regex libraries allow you to distinguish between a _match_ and a _search_, apparently c# does not, which requires you to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

The Following Should work: `\d{5}\-\d{3}[01]`